# VirtualMachine Ubuntu 18.04 Attribute Byte

Tags: c

I’m trying to change the attribute byte to allow a white text and a blue background, I currently have 0x07 light grey on black. I can get blue background, but not white text. I’ve tried 1x15 1x15f and neither work. Any feedback or links resources would be appreciated.

```
 void kmain(void)
 {
     const char *str = "my first kernel";
     char *vidptr = (char*)0xb8000;  //video mem begins     here.
     unsigned int i = 0;
     unsigned int j = 0;

   /* this loops clears the screen
  * there are 25 lines each of 80 columns; each element takes 2 bytes */
     while(j < 80 * 25 * 2) {
/* blank character */
         vidptr[j] = ' ';
/* attribute-byte - light grey on black screen */
         vidptr[j+1] = 0x07;         
          j = j + 2;
  }
```

Comment: What is `1x15` supposed to mean? Are you sure that you understand what the `0x` in e.g. `0x07` means? Perhaps you need to read a little more about *hexadecimal* notation?

Comment: `0x1f` should produce a blue background with white foreground.